# Invalid application archive - resource name is not valid (.idea/)

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to build my  Blackberry app using Phonegap & the Webworks SDk but I receive the following error

> invalid application archive - resource name is not valid(.idea/).

I've found the .idea file in question. It was located in the archive folder which is generated by the Blackberry webworks packager but I'm not sure what to do with it or if it can be safely deleted

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

I'm using the "Webstorm" IDE which generates the .idea folder and dumps it under your directory. It can be safely deleted. I rebuilt the Blackberry app with no error messages. In the meantime, I also read that the Blackberry WebWorks Packager has issues with certain naming conventions ("_" etc).

Comment: How do I instead have the build script skip these hidden files? I need the file to be in that directory in my development environment so I can use Komodo IDE (.komodotools file)